# What is right way to query "Many-Many-Many" relationship with EF 4.1?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

The Model as below:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> FollowingTags {get;set;}
}

public class Tag
{
    public int Id
    public virtual ICollection<User> Followers {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts {get;set;}
}

public class Post    {
    public int Id
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags {get;set;}
}
```

That means there are two many-to-many from User to Post, perhaps it can be called a M:M:M relationship.

Now, if I want to find all posts with tags that followed by a certain User. I wonder what is the best practice with EF 4.1?

If use ADO.NET, I think  joining two joint tables is effective way, but joint tables are hidden in EF, then how to do it ? I know some solutions, but the performance is not good, because the generated SQL not good enough. so I ask for a good query to get good performance.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(from p in db.Posts
from t in p.Tags
from f in t.Followers
where f.Id == id
select p).Distinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "include" modifier in your query like:

context ctx = new context() // context is the entity context in this case

var query = from p in ctx.posts.include("tags.users")
            where p.tags.Followers.ID = TargetUserID

This should cover it

Comment: "p.tags" is a collection, that cannot ".Followers", and so on.